# How To Make A Simple Dice System

Tags: c#, probability, code-snippets

First, I want to express that I am writing this with the intentions of following the guidelines of the website itself, which states that anyone may document their work to help facilitate the eventuality of needing it again in the future. Here is a screenshot of where it says that:
[image]

The question is quite simple, how would someone hoping to create a d20-stylized game, create a dice roller class for the battle systems and general use within the game's framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a "Dicebag" is quite simple; it takes little to no effort at all to write it. However, there are a few things that need to be described before continuing. A die(plural "dice") can never be zero or negative, thus when writing the class we need to prepare for that in mind. We will wrap the parameter overloads with our own "Dice" enum, which will be, unconditionally, an unsigned integer. Doing this will assist in keeping all sorts of undefined behavior away. We will also add +1 to the returned value to ensure that the number is never 0, which, as I have said, is impossible for a physical die to achieve.

Using these rules and laws, here is the class prescribed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Utilities {
    /**
     * Original Author: Gordon Kyle Wallace, "Krythic"
     * 
     * This class is designed to emulate/facilitate the rolling of real-world
     * dice within a d20 stylized game/system.
     * 
     * License:
     * There is not one; this snippet may be used/modified by anyone for
     * any arbitrary reason. I, Gordon Kyle Wallace "Krythic", lay no claim upon
     * this document, the program it ultimately produces, or the thought-patterns
     * that may—or may not—emerge from using it.
     * 
     * This disclaimer may be deleted at your whim.
     * 
     * ~Krythic
     */
    public class DiceBag {
        public enum Dice : uint {
            /// <summary>
            /// This can be considered a double-sided coin;
            /// used to delimit a 50/50 probability.
            /// </summary>
            D2 = 2 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Tetrahedron
            /// A 4 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D4 = 4 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Cube
            /// A 6 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D6 = 6 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Octahedron
            /// A 8 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D8 = 8 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Pentagonal Trapezohedron
            /// A 10 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D10 = 10 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Dodecahedron
            /// A 12 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D12 = 12 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Icosahedron
            /// A 20 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D20 = 20 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Rhombic Triacontahedron
            /// A 30 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D30 = 30 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Icosakaipentagonal Trapezohedron
            /// A 50 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D50 = 50 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Pentagonal Hexecontahedron
            /// A 60 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D60 = 60 ,
            /// <summary>
            /// A Zocchihedron
            /// A 100 Sided Die
            /// </summary>
            D100 = 100
        };

        private Random _rng;

        public DiceBag() {
            _rng = new Random();
        }

        /**
         * The default dice-rolling method. All methods link to this one.
         */
        private int InternalRoll( uint dice ) {
            return 1 + _rng.Next( ( int )dice );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls the specified dice.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The d.</param>
        /// <returns>The Number rolled.</returns>
        public int Roll( Dice d ) {
            return InternalRoll( ( uint )d );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls the chosen dice then adds a modifier
        /// to the rolled number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dice">The dice.</param>
        /// <param name="modifier">The modifier.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int RollWithModifier( Dice dice , uint modifier ) {
            return InternalRoll( ( uint )dice ) + ( int )modifier;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls a series of dice and returns a collection containing them.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The d.</param>
        /// <param name="times">The times.</param>
        /// <returns>A Collection Holding the dice rolls.</returns>
        public List<int> RollQuantity( Dice d , uint times ) {
            List<int> rolls = new List<int>();
            for( int i = 0 ; i < times ; i++ ) {
                rolls.Add( InternalRoll( ( uint )d ) );
            }
            return rolls;
        }
    }
}
```

How to Use this class:

Implementing the class is quite simple. First, you must create an instance of the "Dicebag" class, and then choose the method of your choice. Here is an example that rolls 1d20(One Twenty Sided Die):

```
DiceBag bag = new DiceBag();
Console.WriteLine( bag.Roll( DiceBag.Dice.D20 ) );
```

How to apply a modifier attribute to a roll:

Again, this is quite simple. We will use a second method called "RollWithModifier", and using the chosen dice, also feed in a second overload with any unsigned integer of our choosing. Here is a snippet, which among using a d20, will add a modifier of 22 to the final roll:

```
DiceBag bag = new DiceBag();
Console.WriteLine( bag.RollWithModifier( DiceBag.Dice.D20 , 22 ) );
```

You may also notice that I took the liberty of adding a helper method for mass-dice-rolling. Which could prove useful in certain scenarios. The snippet below will generate 131 dice rolls using a d20:

```
DiceBag bag = new DiceBag();
List<int> rolls = bag.RollQuantity( DiceBag.Dice.D20 , 131 );
for( int i = 0 ; i < rolls.Count ; i++ ) {
   Console.WriteLine( rolls[ i ] );
}
```

And that's all there is to it.